# Location.getProvider always return "fused" not GPS or Network

Tags: android, android-location

I am using the fused location API:

```
        locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationrequest.setInterval(interval);
        locationrequest.setFastestInterval(interval);
        locationrequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);

        locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(locationClient, locationrequest, this);
```

And whenever I get a location, I do loc.getProvider and I always get the string "Fused".

I was expecting Network vs GPS or some other indication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the FusedLocationApi - it combines services in order to reduce power usage and for a variety of other reasons.

If you need to use a specific provider, you'll want http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html

As that page says, this is not the recommended way to get location.

If you're interested in handling the accuracy of returned locations, it's better to do this on an update by update basis - using [Location.getAccuracy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy())

Comment: Thank you, I would like the fused api to get me the location. But I want to know if the location came from GPS or Network as eachone has different accuracy and I want to handle the location differently.

Comment: The whole point of the fused location provider is that it isn't giving you a signal from just a single provider - every location you get may have information/corrections from all available providers.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting really bad GPS results with MAUI. It would jump all around, sometimes up to a mile away. I had to use the old way (from Xamarin) to get a good GPS reading. I also had to force the provider string to "gps" otherwise it would pick that god awful fused provider that is the worst for accuracy. here is my MainActivity.cs file from the MAUI app I am working on. It simply reads in a location as soon as it is ready and builds a new Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.Location() object and populates it with the fields from the Android.Locations.Location object returned by the Location Manager.

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity, ILocationListener
{
    private LocationManager MyLocMgr;
    private string LocationProvider;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        //Initialize android.
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        #region Location.

        // Start listening to the GPS if it can be reached.
        MyLocMgr = GetSystemService(LocationService) as LocationManager;
        MyLocMgr.RequestLocationUpdates("gps", 1000, 0.0001F, this);
 
        #endregion
    }


    public void OnLocationChanged(Android.Locations.Location location)
    {
        MainPage.MyCurrentLocation = new Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.Location()
        {
            Latitude = location.Latitude,
            Longitude = location.Longitude,
            Altitude = location.Altitude,
            Accuracy = location.Accuracy,
            VerticalAccuracy = location.VerticalAccuracyMeters,
            Timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow)
        };
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {

    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {

    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {

    }
}
```